# Finding the address of a main function local variable

Tags: c, nm

Let's say we have the following C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  char *a = "askakasd";
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to find my local variable "a", but I don't know how to recognize it looking in this output, where p is the C code compiled:

[image]

Comment: It could be optimised out, since it is never used.

Comment: http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/mu.html

Comment: @Arkadiy, what's the connection of your answer with my question? it's an interesting post, however.

Comment: “Your question cannot be answered because it depends on incorrect assumptions”. Also, reading Hacker's Dictionary is good for your soul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not there. Since the code can't tell at execution time whether it's there or not, the linker removed it to save space.

Comment: So if I use it like this, printf("%s", a), still doesn't appear nothing. I have to ask you, how could I get in nms output a line which describes where "a" is stored?

Comment: You could move `char * a ="askaskasd";` outside of `main`, forcing the name to be made public.